# How to Configure output in Vite like we configure in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, vite

Bellow is my code block, written in webpack. I am trying to change the entry point file name into `app.js` and access its function inside the script tag where this file is called. I want to achieve same result in vite. i can't find vite docs that much helpful for this

```
this is Webpack config file
```

```
entry: {
            app: [
                'regenerator-runtime/runtime.js', // for using async request,
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
            ],
        },
        output: {
            clean: true, // clears output directory before emitting
            asyncChunks: false,
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
            crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: 'ChatSupport',
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            libraryExport: 'default',
            umdNamedDefine: true,
            
        },
```